# Excel 2010 separating registers with the same name on dynamic tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a series of registers in the form of:

```
Name    Value   Other Field
AAA     112     …
AAA     8127    …
AAA     …       …
BBB     …       …
BBB     …       …
CCC     …       …
…       …       …
```

The problem is that Excel sometimes separates my registers so I end up with two filters for `AAA`, for example:

```
[✓] AAA (25) 
[ ] AAA (10) 
[✓] BBB (20)
[✓] CCC (5)
```

So I end up with two different bars for the same `AAA` registers on any graphics.

I have tried searching and replacing them all, the search dialog finds all of them correctly, but the problem persists with *dynamic tables*, this doesn't happen with filters. The only workaround is to copy the registers and pasting them on a new document, until I add new registers and the problem returns.

Comment: Have you tried using the TRIM() function to remove any leading or trailing spaces.  I don't really see why dynamic tables (Pivot tables?) should behave differently from an in place filter but that would be one of the things I try.

Comment: Yes, they're pivot tables (sorry my installation isn't in english), and yes, I've tried that too (I just ordered them, set the first cell and pulled it all the way down, that should do the trick). Another strange thing is that sometimes it even generates empty (0) filters.

Comment: How are the new registers being entered?  Are you doing it manually or are they being copied from some other software?

Comment: Completely manually.